# Connection error: docker compose: Loopback4 + Mongo

Tags: express, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-desktop, loopback4

I run the project with:
clean volumes & containers, then `docker compose up --build`

Tried creating different users for mongo. Made different settings for the docker file. For docker compose.

I assume that the error is somewhere between loopback & mongodb container.

For watch changes i use tsc-watch. Dont know it cause any bugs here, not sure.

## Configuration

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "lympha-backend",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "lympha backend",
  "keywords": [
    "loopback-application",
    "loopback"
  ],
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "engines": {
    "node": "14 || 16 || 18 || 19"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "tsc-watch --target es2017 --outDir ./dist --onSuccess \"node .\"",
    "build": "lb-tsc",
    "build:watch": "lb-tsc --watch",
    "watch": "lb-tsc --watch",
    "lint": "yarn run eslint && yarn run prettier:check",
    "lint:fix": "yarn run eslint:fix && yarn run prettier:fix",
    "prettier:cli": "lb-prettier \"**/*.ts\" \"**/*.js\"",
    "prettier:check": "yarn run prettier:cli -l",
    "prettier:fix": "yarn run prettier:cli --write",
    "eslint": "lb-eslint --report-unused-disable-directives .",
    "eslint:fix": "yarn run eslint --fix",
    "pretest": "yarn run rebuild",
    "test": "lb-mocha --allow-console-logs \"dist/__tests__\"",
    "posttest": "yarn run lint",
    "test:dev": "lb-mocha --allow-console-logs dist/__tests__/**/*.js && yarn run posttest",
    "docker:build": "docker build -t lympha-backend .",
    "docker:run": "docker run -p 3000:3000 -d lympha-backend",
    "premigrate": "yarn run build",
    "migrate": "node ./dist/migrate",
    "preopenapi-spec": "yarn run build",
    "openapi-spec": "node ./dist/openapi-spec",
    "prestart": "yarn run rebuild",
    "start": "node -r source-map-support/register .",
    "clean": "lb-clean dist *.tsbuildinfo .eslintcache",
    "rebuild": "yarn run clean && yarn run build"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "license": "",
  "files": [
    "README.md",
    "dist",
    "src",
    "!*/__tests__"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@loopback/boot": "^5.0.7",
    "@loopback/core": "^4.0.7",
    "@loopback/repository": "^5.1.2",
    "@loopback/rest": "^12.0.7",
    "@loopback/rest-crud": "^0.15.6",
    "@loopback/rest-explorer": "^5.0.7",
    "@loopback/service-proxy": "^5.0.7",
    "loopback-connector-mongodb": "^5.2.3",
    "tsc-watch": "^6.0.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@loopback/build": "^9.0.7",
    "@loopback/eslint-config": "^13.0.7",
    "@loopback/testlab": "^5.0.7",
    "@types/node": "^14.18.36",
    "eslint": "^8.30.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
    "typescript": "~4.9.4"
  }
}
```

**Docker compose**

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=admin
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
      - mongodb:/data/db

  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./lympha-backend/Dockerfile
    command: ["yarn", "dev"] 
    ports:
      - 4000:3000
    environment:
      NAME: TEST_DEVELOPMENT
      PORT: 3000
      DB_NAME: lympha_db
      DB_USER: root
      DB_PASS: password
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./lympha-backend:/home/node/app
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    links:
      - mongodb

volumes:
  backend:
  mongodb:
```

**Dockerfile**

```
# Check out https://hub.docker.com/_/node to select a new base image
FROM node:16-slim

# Set to a non-root built-in user `node`
USER node

# Create app directory (with user `node`)
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/dist

WORKDIR /home/node/app
RUN pwd

COPY --chown=node package*.json ./

# RUN npm install
RUN yarn

# Bundle app source code
COPY --chown=node . .


# Bind to all network interfaces so that it can be mapped to the host OS
ENV HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=3000

EXPOSE ${PORT}
```

**mongo-init.js**

```
db.createUser({
    user: 'admin',
    pwd: 'password',
    roles: [ 
        { role: 'root', db: 'admin' },
    ]
});

db = db.getSiblingDB('lympha_db');
db.createCollection("lympha_db"); //MongoDB creates the database when you first store data in that database

db.createUser(
    {
        user: "lympha",
        pwd: "lympha",
        roles: [
            {
                role: "readWrite",
                db: "lympha_db"
            }
        ]
    }
);
```

## **Mongo terminal**

[Look at the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXqLS.png)

## **Logs**

**Mongodb logs**

```
Look at the picture
```

**Backend logs**

```
{
  name: 'mongodb',
  connector: 'mongodb',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 27017,
  user: 'admin',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'admin'
}
Server is running at http://127.0.0.1:3000
Try http://127.0.0.1:3000/ping
Connection fails: MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
It will be retried for the next request.
/home/node/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:698
          throw error;
          ^
MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at Timeout.\_onTimeout (/home/node/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:438:30)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
Emitted 'error' event on MongoDataSource instance at:
    at MongoDataSource.postInit (/home/node/app/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/datasource.js:502:16)
    at onError (/home/node/app/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/lib/mongodb.js:325:21)
    at /home/node/app/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/lib/mongodb.js:333:9
    at /home/node/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:695:9
    at /home/node/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:285:23
    at connectCallback (/home/node/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/connect.js:367:5)
    at /home/node/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/connect.js:554:14
    at connectHandler (/home/node/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:286:11)
    at Object.callback (/home/node/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:672:9)
    at Timeout.\_onTimeout (/home/node/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:443:25)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Single',
    setName: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' =\> ServerDescription {
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
            at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect \[as oncomplete\] (node:net:1278:16) {
          name: 'MongoNetworkError'
        },
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 7989795,
        lastWriteDate: null,
        opTime: null,
        type: 'Unknown',
        topologyVersion: undefined,
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        hosts: \[\],
        passives: \[\],
        arbiters: \[\],
        tags: \[\]
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    compatibilityError: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    commonWireVersion: null
  }
}
```

I cant connect lb4 and mongo.

I can start for scratch to figure out what is going on. Ask everything you want, i will do everything is needed as well. Ping me please.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start in compose, it sets up single network. (https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

In short, each container can see another by service name. In your case - **mongodb**, not **localhost**

try to change:

```
    - host: 'localhost',
    + host: 'mongodb',
```